# Função SE, SOMASE ou qual?

Tags: microsoft-excel, funções

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando montar uma fórmula, mas sei menos que o básico sobre Excel. 
Fiz uma planilha para controle de vendas, e coloquei os bolos, doces, salgados, em colunas e até ai tudo certo o total estava dando tudo certo, usei a função SOMA na coluna  mas aí decidi colocar uma coluna para os kits festas e tenho kits para 10,20,30,40,50 até 100 pessoas, e cada um tem um preço, quero uma fórmula que se eu colocasse na coluna por exemplo o 10 e no valor total fosse somado o valor do kit de 10 pessoas e não o 10 em si.

Comment: Talvez fosse uma boa ideia você mostrar como está a tabela pois pelo menos eu não conseguir entender muito bem como ficaram as linhas e colunas.

Comment: Pronto coloquei uma imagem de exemplo. Quero que quando eu colocar na coluna do kit o 20 por exemplo, fosse somado la no total o valor do kit.

Comment: Para que isso seja possível você precisa criar uma tabela de correspondência kit x valor para que o Excel vá buscar o valor através da função PROCV.  Na resposta tem o exemplo de como fazer isso. Você precisa adaptar aquelas informações à sua planilha.

Answer (score 0):

Crei como exemplo a tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloque a formula :

```
=SE(D3="";"";PROCV(D3;A3:B10;2;FALSO))
```

na celula E3 e copie-a até a celula E10

e coloque a formula:

```
=SOMA(E3:E10)
```

na célula E11

Adicione seus kits nas linhas A3 até A10 com os valores nas linhas B3 até B10 e as vendas nas linhas D3 até D10 e terá o valor na celula E11

Answer (score 0):

Fala Leonardo bem?

Você terá que criar uma tabela com os valores e utilizar o "somase" para simplificar a busca.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em outras palavras você esta buscando em uma lista de valores apenas o valor compatível com a sua "chave".

Separei em duas "abas", para evitar que os valores sejam perdidos ou alterados erroneamente no dia a dia.

Segue o link da planilha no google drive, se for isso, pode fazer o download e adaptar para as necessidades ;)

https://goo.gl/gE8tvc

Abraço!